# HTML 5 video shows black screen after video plays

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a video being loaded in the `<video>` tag.

> It is set to play only once i.e it doesn't loop.

After the video finishes playing, it just shows a black screen.
I've tried adding the `poster` attribute but from my understanding, this is used before the video loads and not after. Most of the solutions available are to prevent this black screen before a video, not after and they don't address single play videos.

1. How can I prevent this black screen from showing?
2. Can I add another image or the first frame of the video once the video finishes playing?

```html
<video width="400" autoplay="" muted="" playsinline="" class="" style="max-width:100%;padding:0px;" poster="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0017/4227/4613/files/COST-GRAPH_450x.png?v=9334525452384790062">
    <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0017/4227/4613/files/CG1.25X_compressed.mp4?v=1596956587" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the last frame of the video source is black.

#### poster

A URL for an image to be shown while the video is downloading. If this attribute isn't specified, nothing is displayed until the first frame is available, then the first frame is shown as the poster frame.

And the below shows an example the last frame is ok. is this your expected?

```html
<video controls width="250">

    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/flower.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">

    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

Comment: You're right, the last frame is black. My bad. Thanks!